# How to check for multiple key presses in Python? (Keyboard module)

Tags: python, input, module, keyboard, key

So I'm using the Python keyboard module and I have this code:

```
def keyPressed():
import keyboard
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
            break
    except:
        break
```

I have made it into a thread so that I can seperately take an input from the user and whenever they press the space button it will input what they've entered, rather than having to press enter each time.

Problem is is that once space has been pressed once, the thread ends and I cannot check for space press anymore. If I remove the break in the loop it just repeatedly presses enter.

I'm thinking: Is there a way to set "keyboard.is_pressed('space')" or whatever to false so that I can then remove the break in the loop to keep checking for space press and pressing enter accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The small sleep will stop the repeated presses.

```
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
            keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Salutations! I would do this:

```py
import keyboard

def keyPressed():
    holding = False
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('space') and not holding:  # PRESS
            keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
            holding = True
        elif not keyboard.is_pressed('space') and holding:  # RELEASE
            holding = False
```

(I got rid of the try-except block, I think that's redundant, but correct me if I'm wrong)
Now if you are holding the space button, the variable named 'holding' will be True, and that prevents the code from repeatedly pressing enter.
Moreover, 'holding' will only be False, once you released that button.
Here's a detailed description of what's happening:

- `holding = False`
- Now we press the space button. The code will enter the 'if' part, as 'space' is pressed and `not holding` is `not False`, hence `True`. We perform our desired task (press and release ENTER) and set `holding = True`.
- You are holding the button. We are neither entering the 'if' nor the 'elif' part, as `not holding = not True = False` ('if' part) and we are still holding the button, hence `not keyboard.is_pressed('space') = not True = False` ('elif' part). That means, in this phase we are not doing anything.
- You release the button. Now `not keyboard.is_pressed('space')` becomes `not False = True` and holding is also `True`, hence we enter the 'elif' part and set `holding = False`.

Then we start again.
It also makes sense in an intuitive way:

> You can only press the button if it IS NOT already pressed, and you can only release it if it IS already pressed.

If you want to be more general, you can also try something like:

```py
import keyboard

def keyPressed():
    holding = []
    while True:
        key = mysteriousKeyOrigin()
        if keyboard.is_pressed(key) and key not in holding:  # PRESS
            keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
            holding.append(key)
        elif not keyboard.is_pressed(key) and key in holding:  # RELEASE
            holding.remove(key)
```

In this way, it works with any key given.
Have fun!:)